# Get percent value from total sum row in pivot mode

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i have next data in pivot mode
[my data in pivot mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYlH7.png)

pivot query

```
database('MyDatabase').Test
| summarize AdjValue = sum(AdjValue) by Fylke, ClassSE
| extend p = pack(ClassSE, AdjValue)
| summarize bag=make_bag(p) by Fylke
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag)
```

need to devide each value on rowSum - (value / rowSum * 100 = some percent).

I tried to use join for temporary pivot table but not succesfull. Plese help.

[expected result in pivot mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDx5I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This is not a part of the solution only generation of a sample dataset 
let Test = materialize(range i from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend AdjValue = rand()*100, Fylke = strcat('Fylke_',tostring(toint(rand()*10))), ClassSE = strcat('ClassSE_',tostring(toint(rand()*5))));
// The solution starts here
let sum_by_Fylke_ClassSE = materialize(Test | summarize AdjValue = sum(AdjValue) by Fylke,ClassSE);
let sum_by_Fylke = sum_by_Fylke_ClassSE | summarize Fylke_AdjValue = sum(AdjValue) by Fylke;
sum_by_Fylke
| join sum_by_Fylke_ClassSE on Fylke
| evaluate pivot(ClassSE, sum(AdjValue/Fylke_AdjValue*100), Fylke)
| order by Fylke asc
```

| Fylke | ClassSE_0 | ClassSE_1 | ClassSE_2 | ClassSE_3 | ClassSE_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fylke_0 | 49.395106915030119 | 46.755319585100125 | 0 | 0 | 3.8495734998697557 |
| Fylke_1 | 62.292139898464924 | 5.2693450408156046 | 7.6552025348509991 | 6.2015378618740726 | 18.581774663994409 |
| Fylke_2 | 50.145053387669094 | 1.2587789001232987 | 41.166356893005975 | 7.4298108192016352 | 0 |
| Fylke_3 | 10.564746410722819 | 35.571795098974818 | 9.817452610031193 | 6.7291651195813156 | 37.316840760689857 |
| Fylke_4 | 0 | 11.770542330107656 | 25.250380537085615 | 12.46115402880039 | 50.517923104006343 |
| Fylke_5 | 11.098011115225455 | 24.401878297613749 | 37.849873348947106 | 16.221012456995606 | 10.429224781218091 |
| Fylke_6 | 31.340691613236839 | 53.496440433838153 | 0 | 15.16286795292501 | 0 |
| Fylke_7 | 31.764625835537881 | 34.741929615153026 | 7.9119328065215306 | 6.2721731408556778 | 19.309338601931888 |
| Fylke_8 | 25.3982395190392 | 32.868425203681305 | 28.605169017331683 | 3.0705116629208007 | 10.057654597027003 |
| Fylke_9 | 14.778417432435949 | 29.9861720571239 | 19.118237524156271 | 15.091700930745427 | 21.025472055538462 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VRy27CMBC8I/EPcyOuIgUOPVU9VFX7A0W9ooUsYHDsyF5QU/Hx3ZCUhj5UybK0452ZnXVRYL61CXp8EBBqioKwhmwZKbiD2OARvGuwYc%20RunqtnYmq2jFKEkosGI%20c3nNOgntUJBwtOfvOWSS/YVisY6gwgwTMplMk4VqrE/hN2Jd4KHev5A6sZCWUmbnRrhzPjdu3WJK4Iskm53oxySUoYv0mk2C9ZBeKMSbHo6OUXp4GtB75k3irPHM3HhXtOgbBk%20g6ErYcucuXDtVi2Sy6Mb58hnnPKzi1nRVFBYbRFMw%20S4Nl0%20XLe6F2gu8mHemn59Cge/nXRtWHUuPRCTtdwu/6Gv7SxUcV0oSo7TFI1rfkVzbF9RDt75n%20%200yrEWLJ8TIKKK0%20APCXXEl7AgAA)